# Google App Engine deleted default GCS bucket. Is there a way to restore it?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I was deleting some files from the default bucket of my application and I accidentally deleted also the bucket itself using gsutil rm command.

Is there a way to restore/recreate/bring it back ? I would like to continue to use the free quota and not enable billing.

What I tried to do so far is that (but I'm not sure it is correct).
I first enable billing just to re-create a bucket with the same name:
xxx.appspot.com. In order to be able to do that I verified that I'm the owner of the domain.
I setup the default acl to give my app OWNER access using the service account.
Then I disabled the billing again.

Is the bucket considered like the default bucket create by app engine cloud storage integration and use the free quota tier ?

Comment: The only way to get it back seems to be creating a new project. There is no option to restore the bucket in the console, and there is no documentation on how to restore the bucket if it gets deleted.

Comment: Yeah.. it seem so.. unfortunately. I hope I can avoid that, but not a big problem.. I will re-create it.

Comment: That is very unfortunate. I had the same problem. I tried creating the bucket with the same name (<projectname>.appspot.com) but was refused because I dont own the appspot domain.

Answer (score 3):

Just login to your Cloud Console Dashboard, go to AppEngine and select settings then Create Default Bucket.

I deleted mine severally and recreated it again!

Comment: You can find this is App Engine > Settings > Default Cloud Storage Bucket > Create

Answer (score 0):

No there is no way to restore a deleted bucket or object inside a bucket.
DELETE operation comes under strong global consistency. Keep in mind that you can use Google Cloud Storage only after enabling billing for your project. It's not free.

Comment: If you use python in google-app-engine, and use the default bucket created for your project, it is under free quota of 5GB (at the time of this writing). Their documentation on the subject: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/googlecloudstorageclient/activate#Using_the_Default_GCS_Bucket

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the App Engine settings Cloud Console page no longer has functionality to restore the default GAE buckets. Instead you can perform the restore via the gcloud instructions below:

The default (`<project_id>.appspot.com`) and staging
(`staging.<project_id>.appspot.com`) buckets can be recreated by a project
Owner/Editor running
[gcloud beta app repair](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/app/repair).
The Google Container Registry (GCR) bucket (`<region>.artifacts.<project_id>.appspot.com`) will be recreated
upon next app engine deployment or image push to GCR in that region.